# ¿Cómo autorizar esta operación en la terminal de Linux?

Tags: c, linux, línea-de-comandos

Empleo Windows 10, adapté Visual Studio para el lenguaje C e instalé MinGW como compilador. Con esto, Visual Studio me permite editar, compilar y ejecutar en C. Además, Visual Studio me da acceso a una consola de comandos donde puedo emplear comandos de Linux.

**Al intentar borrar dos archivos .c junto a sus respectivos .exe** (hechos los cuatro desde Visual Studio) de una carpeta, **solo pude eliminar los .c**. Los .exe no se eliminaron porque necesitaba "permisos de administrador". Concedía dichos permisos y, acto seguido, **me pedían permisos de otra entidad**. Básicamente, no lograba pasar de esta ventana emergente:

[image: Error Unix]

Decidí que, al haber sido compilado desde Visual Studio, debería ir a Visual Studio, abrir la terminal y **emplear el comando rmdir para eliminar el archivo**. Pero si intentaba ejecutarlo, me aparecía lo siguiente por consola:

[image: Error Unix 2]

De esta manera, no sé cómo obtener esos permisos necesarios para poder ejecutar el borrado del archivo.

Es de mencionar que soy nuevo en este mundillo, luego es muy probable una mala configuración de algún elemento de VS o MinGW.

Gracias.

Comment: Soy plenamente consciente de que mi explicación tal vez no esté bien formulada porque no sé muy bien cómo explicar el tema de comandos y de C al ser nuevo en esto. Si necesitan de alguna edición para la pregunta, díganmelo y me pondré a ello lo antes posible. Gracias.

Comment: Tu etiqueta dice Linux pero veo q tu OS es Windows. Y en vez de `rmdir` usa `del`, segun leo aca (el primero es para dirs y el segundo para files). [Delete files in Windows](https://geniushub.io/how-to-delete-files-folders-directories-cmd-windows-command-line-prompt-del-rmdir/)

Comment: Como he dicho, no sé orientarme bien todavía. El caso es que estamos empleando una máquina Unix en la escuela, pero yo quiero probar otro tipo de cosas. He decidido descargar VSC como IDE para C y, como es necesario, el compilador MinGW. En VSC, hay opción para manejar la terminal desde el propio IDE (la terminal de la imagen adjunta) y parece ser que esta terminal emplea comandos de Unix, pues los uso para moverme entre los archivos y crear documentos y funcionan. Sin embargo, el comando para eliminar, como bien explico, no me funciona, pues requiere de permisos.

Comment: Imagino que usted lee el comando de Windows en la terminal debido a que, en última instancia, estoy empleando Windows. Imagino que habrá un intérprete haciendo de intermediario entre los comandos de Linux y los de Windows (muchos "imagino", lo sé).

Comment: A que te refieres con probar otro tipo de cosas? VSCode no es un IDE (es un text editor, IDE son como Eclipse, IntellijIdea, CodeBlock, ect). La terminal usa los comandos que ingreses y sean parte de tu OS (de otra forma, error); `cd` es lo mismo tanto en Windows como Linux. Respecto a lo de eliminar leiste la web que te comparti? Creo que hablaba de eso...

Comment: Tu suposicion es exacta. Estoy viendo este hilo porque dice Linux. Y no existe tal cosa como ese interprete; a lo mucho puedes hacer algo como `system("cls||clear");` para limpiar screen tanto en Windows como en Linux (imagino que te habras dado cuenta del truco para ello el `||`). Por ultimo, no veo nada de Linux en tu pregunta.

Comment: Respecto a la web que compartió, estoy muy liado este finde. Lo leeré el lunes con total calma. En cuanto al error de llamar IDE a un editor de texto, se me escapó. Y, por último, ¿podría usted proponer una edición para adecuar mi pregunta a mi duda? Podría hacerlo yo, pero usted es el más indicado y, además, ganaría puntos (creo).

Comment: Aunque viendo su reputación, no sé si tiene el privilegio de sugerir ediciones aún. Ya me dice usted si puede o, en caso contrario, si lo hago yo.

Comment: Pues he probado los comandos propuestos en la web que usted me recomendó y nada. Sigue saliendo un error, aunque es otro error diferente. Ahora parece ser que no es correcto el parámetro. El error es el siguiente: Remove-Item : No se encuentra ningún parámetro de posición que acepte el argumento 'Ejercicio_1.exe'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Del /F "Ejercicio_1.exe"                 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand